# Why can't I block access to files with .htaccess ( order not allowed here)?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, apache2, ddos

I've tried everything. I read other how to threads here and elsewhere. I have the following in my apache2 site configuration file:

```
 <Directory  /var/www/html/site_root/>
   AllowOverride All
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

There is no other occurence of "AllowOverride" in the site conf file so it's not a case of something earlier in the file overriding this (don't even know if that's possible). I also tried '/var/www/html/site_root'.

If I try either of the following (or both) in my /var/www/html/site_root/.htaccess file:

```
<Files .htaccess>
  Order Allow,Deny
  Deny from all
</Files>

<Files "xmlrpc.php">
   Order Allow,Deny
   Deny from all
</Files>
```

I get 520s and the whole site is crashed. I also tried /xmlrpc.php or "xmlrpc.php" without "" and ./xmlrpc.php etc. No matter what I do my error log is full of:

```
[Thu Dec 03 18:05:25.628237 2015] [core:alert] [pid 6956] [client 192.168.0.1:56529] /var/www/html/site_root/.htaccess: order not allowed here
```

How can this be and why is this so difficult to do?

My purpose is to block access to /xmlrpc.php.  This is an absolute Achilles heel for WordPress. It is very easy to crash and burn any site by just hitting this over and over and over again. For some reason WordPress leaves it wide open by default and Cloudflare is not able to detect or protect against these attacks. They happen all the time and it brings down the server completely.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well did you restart your server after you made changes to apache2.config? Secondly there is a difference between order allow,deny AND order deny,allow

Try using this

```
<Files xmlrpc.php>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
</Files>
```

You can also disable the XML-RPC Feature, from the system itself. Just put this in your wp-config

```
add_filter('xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false');
```

**Update: Some clarification:**

I agree with jason, blocking xmlrpc.php at the htaccess level is always a much better idea because even if you disable it through the filter, the site still goes through the whole request cycle. Here filters is just being used as a safeguard from someone getting in, but the site is still open to DDOS attacks. **In short usage of filters is only for people who are using it for some other purposes and not finding an escape from DDOS attacks, for eg if someone doesn't have access to the htaccess file.**

Comment: I know there is a difference... but this shouldn't cause server errors should it? Are you saying mine is wrong and it has to be order deny,allow instead of order allow, deny?  I didn't know about this second method in wp-config and that probably should work but I would still like to be able to limit access to other files perhaps like this.  For example I might like to deny (or allow) access by IP to wp-login.php.

Comment: I forgot to add yes I definitely restarted the server.

Comment: if you are using Order Allow,Deny what it means is that by default you are denying everybody so you dont need "deny from all". Yes you can also allow access to certain ip's by using "allow from 127.122.1.2/8069"

Comment: I tried it your way:  <Files xmlrpc.php>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
</Files>  It still causes 520 errors across the whole site. Even though I have other options to protect xmlrpc.php I would still like toe be able to use deny allow in general but I can't.  I still get this.   [core:alert] [pid 1225] [client 54.177.21.23:58390] /var/www/html//.htaccess: order not allowed here, referer: http://wwwgoogle.com/   (P.S. I wish I could figure out how to make line breaks in a comment without submitting it)

Comment: The configurations are correct, it might be something else causing it. Try searching the whole config file for "AllowOverride None". Secondly ask your host if you are allowed to change the order directive. One more thing you can test is by replacing all "AllowOverride All" to "AllowOverride Limit" and then restart the service by "service apache2 reload"

Comment: I have my own VPS so I can do whatever I want.  There is nothing in the vhost config that could be overriding it. There is in the master config file (apache2.conf) but I thought that I could configure this at the vhost level? I was advised by someone else that it's bad to set "AllowOverride All" globally so what is the config I need to set to say "Leave this up to the vhosts configuration otherwise do this?"  There should be a way right? If I were to remove this AllowOverride None from apach2.conf then what would I need to add to set a default but let the vhost config override it? Thanks.

Comment: To be honest if i were you, i wont even waste that much time and instead just delete the xml-rpc file, as you are not using it anyways

Comment: I know there are many different solutions for dealing with xmlrpc.php - that's not really the main point of my question, I just used this as an illustrative example. My main problem and the problem I am trying to solve is why can't I use order allow deny? I want to use it on other things that are not so easily dealt with as just "delete the file". Perhaps I wasn't that clear.  Besides just deleting the file, your alternative 403 proposal above also worked. Renaming the file is yet another option as is changing the WordPress wp-config.

Comment: @omer Farooq deleting xmlrpc.php is not a long term solution, because any Wordpress update will add it back in.  Blocking at the .htaccess level is better than adding a filter because even if you block it in Wordpress, wordpress loads.  I had a server under attack with about 2400 requests per minute for that file, each loading wordpress.

Comment: thanks @Jason, i have added more clarification to my answer

Answer (score 0):

**The best answer I found is this:**

If your server is an Apache, you can block access before WordPress is even reached with one line in your .htaccess:

```
Redirect 403 /xmlrpc.php
```

You can add another line to keep the response short:

```
ErrorDocument 403 "die"
```

That will send a very minimal response (three bytes plus HTTP headers), and it will save your resources for better traffic.

Source:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/156522/restrict-access-to-xmlrpc-php

**Please** go vote up the answer at the wordpress stack, by user @toscho.  I don't have enough reputation. Toscho's answer is is way better than the accepted answer because you can deny access in .htaccess and still burn up server resources loading the 404 in Wordpress.  His answer actually saves you one byte over mine.